# Passing structs by pointer in C89

Tags: c, c89

I am working with a C89 compiler and I'm coming across some pointer typing error.

Calling code:

```
struct cpu_state_type cpu_state;
//Stuff here....
foo()
{
    print_out_cpu(&cpu_state);
}
```

Print_out_cpu is defined elsewhere and the H file is #included in.

```
struct cpu_state_type
{
  int r[12];
};
void print_out_cpu(struct cpu_state_type *c);
```

I get error:

`error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'print_out_cpu'`

As best as I can understand,`&cpu_state` returns type `cpu_state_type*`, so I am confused.

Comment: Can you try to cast to `(cpu_state_type*)` and see if it works/crashes?

Comment: Where is `struct cpu_state_type` defined?

Comment: pajton: it errors on that cast. Adding (struct cpu_state_type*) makes it work better, but then says it can't find print_out_cpu(!!).

Comment: "adding a cast and see if it works" should _never_ be the answer to a problem.

Comment: @Paul: you are saying that with explicit cast to `struct cpu_state_type*` there's no match for the `print_out_cpu` function - that makes me think you have conflicting declaration of that function somewhere.

Comment: @nos I was trying to get more information about the problem. If I meant it to be a solution I'd post this as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure the prototype has the `*` in it?  If I compile (`gcc -std=c89`) the following code, I get that exact error:

```
  struct cpu_state_type {
     int r[12];
  };

  // note that it is the structure as the param here (not the pointer)
  void print_out_cpu(struct cpu_state_type c);
  struct cpu_state_type cpu_state;

  foo()
  {
     print_out_cpu(&cpu_state);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems, so I wonder if it's an error in your include statement or in the file, etc.

It'll be difficult to determine the cause of the error without seeing more of the source. Try creating a source file like:

> #include  struct cpu_state_type cpu_state;
>
> void foo() {
>       print_out_cpu(&cpu_state); 
>   }

If that doesn't trigger the problem, keep adding things until it does.
If it does trigger the problem, extract the pertinent parts of the header file into your source (and remove the #include) and try again.

Comment: #include struct cpu_state_type cpu_state; ?